# Importing eclipse project stuck

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, zk

I want to import [this project](https://github.com/zkoss-demo/zk-rxdemo)  into eclipse. I have downloaded it as zip, extracted and when I go to menu **import->Gradle Project->zk demo**
it stays stuck at 50%.

Is this the wrong way to do it?

Please help!

Eclipse Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)

[image: the picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just download IntelliJ IDEA for JAVA.

Download GITHUB for Desktop,set up your **git.exe** location and then click Import.

Run ***gradlew startJettyRunner***

Go To http://localhost:8080/zk-rxdemo it works!